# Переключение вида мобильного устройства на стандартный вид инструмента разработчика

Tags: веб-программирование, google-chrome, отладка

Есть вид

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каким образом настраивается внешний вид (чтобы отображался только внешний вид сайта ishop.ru), чтобы отображался сам сайт и исчезла строка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

нужно нажать на иконку мобильных устройств в левом верхнем углу инструментов разработчика, бои cntl+shift+M[image: введите сюда описание изображения]